# similar C# .net lambda search for java 7 generic list

Tags: java, lambda, generic-list

Hi I have these lambda expression in c#.net for generic list "**Tree**" and I'm trying to find something similar to that in java 7

```
Tree.Where(x => x.LeftChildId == Id || x.RightChildId == Id).FirstOrDefault()
Tree.Where(x => x.Id == NodesCurrentId).First()
```

is there a way to do this without an external library?

Comment: Java8 brought lambda support, but there's no native `Tree` structure

Comment: Yes @َAaron...sorry I should added this info... Tree is the generic list that I'm trying to search into...List<Node>  Tree = new ArrayList<Node>()

Comment: Ok, then you'll be interested in [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). I'll write an answer showcasing its use in the specific cases you mentionned, but you should definitely check the package documentation :)

Comment: Sure...First assumes that the item that I'm looking should be there but FirstOrDefault search for it and if it didn't find the item returns null

Comment: I just noticed the version requirement in the title. I guess I'll delete my answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 does not have something as convenient as this (Lambdas and LINQ equivalent), those things were added in Java 8 (so it sounds like it's time to upgrade).

The Java 7 equivalent would be to use a traditional loop:

```
Node result = defaultValue;
int Id = ...;
for(Node n : tree) {
    if(n.LeftChildId == Id || n.RightChildId == Id) {
        result = n;
        break;
    }
}
```